# How implement css mixes in styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I used in my projects some base classes like text-lg, text-md..., .container, etc.
And usually I wrote classes in this way :

```
<div class="article text-lg container">some content</div>
```

How can I do something like this using styled-components? Create mixins for these classes, or just mix the use of of styled-components and css classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [css helper](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css) to create your base classes and combine them.

```
const container = css`
  padding: 20px;
`;
const article = css`
  max-width: 1920px;
`;
const textLg = css`
  font-size: 3rem;
`;

const CustomDiv = styled.div`
  ${container + article + textLg}

  /* other styles here */
  background: black; 
  color: white;
`;
```

---

Or if you already have an existing stylesheet (for example a CSS library such as Bootstrap), you can just combine them using [`attrs`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs). This saves you the time of having to rewrite your CSS in JS. Read here for official docs: https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#can-i-use-css-frameworks

```
const CustomDiv = styled.div.attrs(props => ({
  className: "article text-lg container",
}))`
  /* other styles here */
  background: black; 
  color: white;
`;
```

Basically, the output will be your custom generated class with `background` & `color` CSS properties in augmentation of `article`, `text-lg`, and `container` classes which is defined in your stylesheet

[image: HTML codes]

[image: CSS codes]

Comment: is it normal practice to combine these moments ? Or better way -> create styled mixins for each class like: 

`export const textLg = css
  font-size: 3rem;

export const container = css
  max-width: 1920px;
`

 and paste them in styled components?

Comment: That is 1 way to do it as well if you are making everything from scratch. The general advantage of the information I gave is if you already have an existing stylesheet that you do not have the luxury of rewriting into JavaScript. With that regard, it entirely depends on your front-end architecture on which would be the better implementation/practice.